# Regexp replacing all matches in a match x times

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript (from node.js) and I have a string:

```
:: something: something
::: something: more
```

I want to replace all the individual ":"s a at the start with a &nbsp; but I don't want the ':' in the middle to be replaced. If there's two colons, then only two spaces should be put in, if there's only one; one space (you get the idea...)
So the string should become:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp; something: something
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; something: more
```

I've tried this:

```
replace(/(:)|([^\n]*\n)/g,"&nbsp;$2")
```

which is very close to working, but it places an extra space at the start of each line and it requires a line break after every line otherwise it will replace all ':' on that line. Using this code on the example, it returns:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; something: something
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; something&nbsp; more
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
replace(/^\s*(:+)/gm,function(_,m) {return new Array(m.length+1).join("&nbsp;");});
```

That "new Array" lark is basically a cheap way of doing something like PHP's [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/str-repeat). The important thing is that this will only replace colons at the start of a line.

EDIT to allow leading spaces.

Comment: you may want to explain that the `m` flag treats `^` as "start of line" and `$` as end of line. Anyway, +1 for beating me :P

Comment: It doesn't seam to work... I tried using the string ":: test \n ::: test" and it only replaced the first line. But still very good +1

Comment: @mdsimmo That'd be because of the space before the colons. Would you like me to edit the code to accept leading spaces?

Comment: Ah, of course... no need for you to edit it, here's what I found to work: replace(/^\s*:+/gm,function(m) {return new Array(m.length).join("&nbsp;");});

Comment: @mdsimmo: you can use `replace(/(^\s*)(:+)/gm,function(m) {return m[1]+new Array(m[2].length+1).join("&nbsp;");});`

Comment: @mdsimmo That would include the space(s) in the length of the result, which isn't what you want as far as I can tell.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Sorry but I don't speak fluently the Daleks language.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The Daleks are supreme!